# DRF: Remove field on model serializer after validation but before creation (on CreateAPIView)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a contact form on a site that is posting to a `CreateAPIView` to create a new instance of a model (that is eventually emailed to the admin). On my serializer I have a honeypot field to help reject spam.

The model:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    name = ...
    message = ...
```

and serializer:

```
class MessageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    # Honeypot field
    url = serializers.CharField(allow_blank=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = '__all__'

    def validate_url(self, value):
        if value and len(value) > 0:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Spam')
        return value
```

and view:

```
class MessageView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    ''' Create a new contact form message. '''
    serializer_class = MessageSerializer
```

My problem is that as it stands, when I post to this view, I get the error:

> TypeError: Got a `TypeError` when calling `Message.objects.create()`. This may be because you have a writable field on the serializer class that is not a valid argument to `Message.objects.create()`. You may need to make the field read-only, or override the MessageSerializer.create() method to handle this correctly.

so obviously the seriazlier is attempting to save the `url` field to the model in `CreateApiView.perform_create()`

I tried adding `read_only` to the serializer field, but this means that the `url_validate` method is skipped altogether.

How can I keep the field on the serializer until validation has occurred, removing it before the `serializer.save()` is called in `perform_create()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can do this overriding the create method like:

```
class MessageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    # Honeypot field
    url = serializers.CharField(allow_blank=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = '__all__'

    def validate_url(self, value):
        if value and len(value) > 0:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Spam')
        return value

    def create(self, validated_data):
        data = validated_data.pop('url')
        return Message.objects.create(**data)
```

Comment: Ha, I figured it out and posted exactly as you did. You can have the points ;)

Comment: thanks for your response but `Message.objects.create(**data)` is incorrect you should pass `validated_data` instead I mean `Message.objects.create(**validated_data)`

Answer (score 1):

OK, I didn't read the error correctly. As it clearly says:

> override the MessageSerializer.create() method to handle this correctly.

I was looking at overwriting the `CreateAPIView.create()` method which didn't make sense.

This works:

```
class MessageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    # Honeypot field
    url = serializers.CharField(allow_blank=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = '__all__'

    def validate_url(self, value):

        if value and len(value) > 0:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Error')
        return value

    def create(self, validated_data):
        if "url" in validated_data:
            del validated_data["url"]
        return Message.objects.create(**validated_data)
```